# Many jars libraries version compatibiity

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, version

For example I have the following hibernate stuff in my pom.xml:

```
<!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now it is working good. But at the moment I need to change version of hibernate core to 5. I am afraid affection of my change. As I understand it is rarity if library has back compatibility. But after changing major version it is absolutely impossible.

How can I determine respective versions of remain hibernate stuff ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the team (`Hibernate` in this case) should provide a compatibility matrix of its various libraries.

Even if they don't, it's generally not that difficult to determine that  yourself. The latest versions of all the libraries should generally be compatible, so if you intend to upgrade everything to the latest, the upgrade is likely to go smooth.

In your case, `hibernate-core`, `hibernate-envers` and `hibernate-entitymanager` appear to [follow the same version](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/) nos., so you could use `5.0.0.Beta2` for these libs. Just use the latest versions of the rest of the [libraries](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate) (almost all of them look like utilities, so I'd expect them to be compatible with the core libs above).

You're going to have to try the combinations to see which one works. In these cases, having a strong set of test suites in place usually helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maven Bill of materials (BOM) provides such a feature where we can include the artifacts which we need, however the versions need not be explicitly defined and the versions would be referred from the bom file which would help maintain the latest versions of the defined artifacts.
More details and examples are provided at this link:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Another with a JBoss example which I found:
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/maven-tutorials/jboss-maven/maven-and-jboss-how-to-use-boms

Comment: Can you provide solution for my concrete question?