# Spring and Maven: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Tags: spring, maven

SessionFactory creation failed with below error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean wit h name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-con text.xml]: Initialization of bean
>   failed; nested exception is org.springframewor
>   k.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
>   'org.spring framework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor':
>   Cannot create inner be an '(inner bean)' of type
>   [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.Transacti onInterceptor]
>   while setting bean property 'transactionInterceptor'; nested exce
>   ption is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating  bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'transactionMan ager' while setting bean property
>   'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.
>   springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
>   bean with na me 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root
>   -context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting b ean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.fac tory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defin ed in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:
>   Implementing class

pom.xml

```
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--
        Core utilities used by other modules.
        Define this if you use Spring Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core)
        Define this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, spring-beans)
        Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, spring-beans)
        This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection Container and is generally always defined
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, Quartz, and Freemarker integration
        Define this if you need any of these integrations
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-aop, spring-context)
        Define this if you use Spring Transactions or DAO Exception Hierarchy
        (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
        Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, and iBatis.
        (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
        Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and Portlet Environments
        (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
        Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web)
        Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web)
        Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*)
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and TestNG
        This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Spring configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>


    <bean name="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>net.wdc.testinglist.model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
                hibernate.show_sql=true
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean name="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Most probably an incompatibility of versions between Spring and Hibernate. Try to check with a compatibility matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm to changed hibernate libs same like there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360197/many-jars-libraries-version-compatibiity
And then I added asm3.3.1.  It helped me.